# Path similarity score between **good** vs **bad** and **good** vs **better** in wordNet

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to understand the path similarity score given by wordNet between 2 Synsets

```
    good = wn.synset('good.n.01')
    bad = wn.synset('bad.n.01')
    better = wn.synset('better.n.01')
    print good.path_similarity(better)
    print good.path_similarity(good)
    print good.path_similarity(bad)
```

outputs are

```
    0.166666666667
    1.0
    0.2
```

here score between good and better is 0.16666 and score in good and bad is 0.2 and ofcorse score is 1.0 for good and good. 
but how can score between good and bad is greater than good and better as they both have almost same semantic meaning

So am i missing something here , is this not the way path similarity works , can someone explain me this ?

Comment: Note: `Word != Synset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose a wrong synset for "good":

```
good = nltk.wordnet.wordnet.synset('good.n.03')
good.path_similarity(better)
#0.5
good.path_similarity(bad)
#0.33333333333333
```

Comment: how would i know that which is correct synset for a particular word ?

Comment: Look at it's hypersets().

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using the proper synset:

http://labs.fc.ul.pt/dishin/

good-noun-3 vs bad-noun-1

```
Measure MICA/DiShIn (Ex/In)trinsic  Similarity
Resnik  MICA    intrinsic   3.49406003202
Lin MICA    intrinsic   0.459704995741
Jiang&Conrath   MICA    intrinsic   0.121755310731
```

good-noun-3 vs better-noun-3

```
Measure MICA/DiShIn (Ex/In)trinsic  Similarity
Resnik  MICA    intrinsic   7.78451947317
Lin MICA    intrinsic   0.876326016756
Jiang&Conrath   MICA    intrinsic   0.455119613313
```